# Why isn't std::hash<const std::string> specialized in std?

Tags: c++, hash

Why isn't `std::hash<const std::string>` specialized in std?

It causes compile error like

```
std::unordered_map<const std::string, int> m;
m.insert(std::make_pair("Foo", 1)); //error
m["Bar"] = 2; // also error
```

Is there any reason for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why isn't `std::hash<const std::string>` specialized in std?

In fact, std didn't specialize any `std::hash<const T>`. The reason is probably it's not needed. For any `std::hash<T>`, the only function it has is an `operator()`, which takes in `const T&` as it's argument. So even if `std::hash<const Foo>` was specialized, it would be exactly the same as `std::hash<Foo>`.

Then go back to the code you were troubling with, it really should've been instead:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m;
```

Here, despite the `key_type` is `std::string`, the actual type of the key is actually `const std::string`, which can be accessed with `decltype(m)::value_type::first_type`.

---

#### Update:

> When you think of concept of hash, the key should not be changed, so specilaization of std::hash looks more appropriate than std::hash. Don't you agree ?

Sure the hash function does not and should not change the key, but in the same time, it probably shouldn't take a copy, so why not go for `std::hash<const T&>`?

One thing to note is that the type being specialized on does not always equal to the argument type. The template argument is more about what type the hash function is related to, not what is passed to the call operator. Similarly, `numeric_limits<T>` expect a non-cv qualified numeric type as type `T`. That doesn't mean `const int` and `const double` don't have their respective limits. Unless you are expecting different behaviors on `hash<T>` and `hash<const T>`, then why should you specialize them twice?

And one other thing to notice is that `std::hash` is really more of a utility class bundled with the `unordered_XXX` family, and is primarily used as the hash function for the unordered family defaultly, or used to define your custom hash function for your custom types to be supplied to the unordered family.

Comment: You make an interesting point, but it doesn't answer the question.  Type `T` can always be implicitly cast to `const T`, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: When you think of concept of hash, the key should not be changed, so specilaization of std::hash<const T> looks more appropriate than std::hash<T>. Don't you agree ?